# Please help me install this USB wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek, adapter

I'm fairly computer savvy, but still super new to Linux so bear with me. If somebody could please walk me through the commands step-by-step, I would be very grateful

The adapter info:
http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v2

Ubuntu 13

Thanks for your attention.
- Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, download the driver zip file from: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
(On the right, click the "download zip" button.)

Open a terminal and `cd` to where the zip is downloaded. (On mine, it is in "Downloads")

Type `unzip rtl8188eu-master.zip`

When it is done, type `cd rtl8188eu-master`

Copy the necessary bin file:  `sudo cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/`

Then type `make all`

When that is done, type `sudo make install`

Comment: Thank you vivid. The installation worked perfectly and my wifi adapter is now recognized. I am also able to connect to my home wifi network, and obtain, what appears to be, a valid IP address from my ISP. (75.157.15.1)

But that's where the functionality ends. If I point my browser to google.com, I get "This web page is not available". If I try to ping it from terminal, I get "unknown host google.com".  Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind. I posted this as a new question.
See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/397515/unable-to-browse-internet